# How to adapt function to new points (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab

Say I have a function that I've obtained as a fit of a certain data set. I want to make that function go through two different points that it doesn't currently go through, while making it so the rest of the function adapts to that change and keeps its shape. Something like this:

[image]

Right now I have a rational fit with 9 coefficients (5th power numerator and 5th power denominator, 5 coefficients in the numerator and 4 coefficients in the denominator while the coefficient of x^5 in the denominator is 1). I can, however, choose a different fit (polynomial, sum of sines etc.) if it would help here.

I have tried changing two coefficients at random to force the function to fit the two new points, but it produces something that doesn't make sense.

Here's what I have:

[image]

[image]

This is a rational fit to a set of Excel data produced with Matlab cftool:

```
p1 = 0.09503;
p2 = 0.8033;
p3 = 2.654;
p4 = 4.375;
p5 = 3.691; 
p6 = 1.221;  
q1 = 6.399;
q2 = 21.65;  
q3 = 34.98;  
q4 = 29.02; 
q5 = 9.704;  
m = (x - 0.9857)./0.1235;
y = (p1*m.^5 + p2*m.^4 + p3*m.^3 + p4*m.^2 + p5*m + p6) ./ (m.^5 + q1*m.^4 + q2*m.^3 + q3*m.^2 + q4*m + q5);
```

I need to make the function go through points (0.78; 0.002) and (1.05473536553; 9.869964329717e-2), while keeping the shape.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a matlab question this seems to be a purely mathematical question. So I'm going to give you my thought on the algorithmic solution I would use:

There is literally an infinite number of ways to do this. From what you've shown I suppose you mean you only want to do vertical scaling and translation.

Let's call the points through which the function should pass `(x_1; y_1)` and `(x_2, y_2)` and your function `f`.

1. Dilate the function by `m` along the `y` axis `f_dilated(x) = m *f(x)` with `m` such that `f_dilated(x_2)-f_dilated(x_1) = y_2 - y_1 = m * (f(x_2) - f(x_1))`. You can then solve for `m` and find `m = (y_2-y_1)/(f(x_2) - f(x_1))`.
2. Now `f_dilated(x)` has the right amplitude to fit your two points but is not centered along the `y` axis.
3. Center the function `f_dilated(x)` by adding a constant: `f_centered(x) = f_dilated(x) + c` so that `f_centered(x_1) = y_1 = f_dilated(x_1) + c`. Solving for c, this means `c = y_1 - f_dilated(x_1)`
4. The final function you're looking for is `f_centered(x)` which can be expanded as: `f_centered(x) = y_1 - (y_2-y_1)/(f(x_2)-f(x_1)) * f(x)`

If I did not make any stupid mathematical mistakes this should work. It is probably very feasible to show that `f_centered(x_1) = y_1` and `f_centered(x_1) = y_2` if you want to be sure.

From that I believe you should not have any trouble implementing a solution in matlab.

I hope this is the algorithm you were looking for, if not please provide more information.